# Tabulator.js move pagination dropdown away from pages (bootstrap4)

Tags: tabulator

I have a pretty simple table:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#producteditor", {
    layout: "fitColumns",
    pagination: "local",
    paginationSize: 25,
    paginationSizeSelector: [50, 100],
    ajaxURL: "api/products",
    movableColumns: false,
    columns: cols,
});
```

the last row looks like this:

[image]

and I fail to find the option to make it look like this:

[image]

what am I looking for? the html code looks like this is one big element:

```
<label>Page Size</label>
<select class="tabulator-page-size" aria-label="Page Size" title="Page Size">
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Tabulator 5.1 as the structure of the footer was changed in that release, you could do it with a little CSS.

And as much as i am loath to use `float` in this day and age it would provide a quick hack to get things working.

Something along the lines of the following CSS should work:

```css
.tabulator-footer .tabulator-paginator>label, .tabulator-footer .tabulator-paginator .tabulator-page-size{
    float:left;
}
```